# Passing a multi-line string to Controller to be encrypted and passed back to a Razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

My application should be a very simple ASP.Net MVC interface that gets a multi-line string from the user, and return it encrypted upon submit.
The problem is that I am using a textArea HTML helper in my View, whenever I submit, the entered values are not passed to the Controller. I placed a breakpoint right at the beginning of the Action in my controller, and all values shows me null after submitting!

This is the View Code

```
<form action="Token" method="post" id="tkn">
        Header<br />
        <textarea id="txtHeader" rows="2" cols="20" form="tkn">Header</textarea><br />
        Payload<br />
        <textarea id="txtPayload" rows="2" cols="20" form="tkn">Load</textarea><br />
        Signature<br />
        <textarea id="txtSignature" rows="2" cols="20" form="tkn">Signature</textarea><br />
        Token<br />
        <textarea id="txtToken" rows="2" cols="20" form="tkn">The Rest</textarea><br />

        <button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

and this is the controller..

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Token(string txtHeader, string txtPayload, string txtSignature, string txtToken)
    {
        txtHeader = txtHeader + " ";
        txtPayload = txtPayload + " ";
        txtSignature = txtSignature + " ";
        txtToken = txtToken + " ";

        return Content(txtHeader + "  " + txtPayload + "  " + txtSignature + "  " + txtToken + "  " );
    }
```

What should I do in order to succeed passing values from the view to the controller? (I don't have a model for this as it's not going to be stored or brought from a data container, just straight forward submit and get value)

Comment: Have you tried setting `name` property for all textareas?

Comment: I haven't.. I'll try that now

Comment: I suggest you to create a viewmodel & bind the string properties with `TextAreaFor`, as this is MVC you can use HTML helpers instead using standard HTML form controls.

Comment: @Tetsuya Yamamoto It did work! apparently the textarea binding works with the `name` not `Id`

Comment: All binding works with the name. When you use an HtmlHelper is sets both the id and the name attributes automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVC binding works on the `name` html attribute, not the `id`

Try this

```
<form action="Token" method="post" id="tkn">
    Header<br />
    <textarea id="txtHeader" name="txtHeader" rows="2" cols="20" form="tkn">Header</textarea><br />
    Payload<br />
    <textarea id="txtPayload" name="txtPayload" rows="2" cols="20" form="tkn">Load</textarea><br />
    Signature<br />
    <textarea id="txtSignature" name="txtSignature" rows="2" cols="20" form="tkn">Signature</textarea><br />
    Token<br />
    <textarea id="txtToken" name="txtToken" rows="2" cols="20" form="tkn">The Rest</textarea><br />

    <button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```